# Can the adjective "paucus" carry this meaning?

Tags: adjective, word-usage

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki), the adjective *paucus*, although typically found in the plural, with a meaning typically pertaining to quantity, can mean:

> *1. few, little*
>
> *Usually plural; very rare in the singular. Mostly pertaining to quantity.*
>
> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paucus#Latin

The usage notes and the inclusion of *little* in the entry *seem* to imply that *paucus* can be used to denote something little, specifically concerning size, but I am extremely doubtful. Thus my question: can *paucus* be used as an adjective meaning *little*, specifically with concerns to size?

Comment: Dictionary trawl:
*pauco foramine* a little way in front of the doorway (Hyginus Fabulae 194); *post paucum tempus* a little while after (Art Poet 203); *pauco numero tritici* small number  (African War 67).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't read too much into Wiktionary.
[Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=paucus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) translate *paucus* as "few, little", and the Wiktionary entry was probably pulled from there.
All examples in L&S seem to pertain to quantity, and I would assume L&S to mention if it could be used for size as well.

I cannot definitively prove a negative, but *paucus* doesn't seem to be able to mean "little" in the sense of "small".
It only means "little" as a synonym of "few".