# What relationships (e.g. derivation) are between pauci and paucus?

Tags: derivation

Keller's Learn to Read Latin says:

> pauci, paucae, pauca few

but I can't find it in Glare's Oxford Latin Dictionary. Is pauci a common or rare Latin word?

In the dictionary, I find:

> paucus few.

What relationships (e.g. derivation) are between the two words?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't they just be the plural and singular form?

Comment: if so, why does the book list pauci as the first form of the word?

Comment: Are you talking about the order? They're male,female and neuter adjectives.

Comment: Related: [Can the adjective "paucus" carry this meaning?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7320)

Answer (score 4):

These are just the singular and plural forms of the same word.

Many dictionaries list the plural as the more "standard" form here, because this is a word that's almost always plural—if you have "a few" of something, that has to be more than one. But the singular *is* attested a couple times, even if it's very rare, so some dictionaries index it by that instead.

For comparison, a word like *tenebrae* is always listed in the plural, because there simply is no singular form. It's clear that the singular should be **tenebra*, if it existed, but there's no such word. Some lexicographers say that *paucus* is so rare that we should consider *paucī* an always-plural word like this. Others say no, *paucus* is rare but it does exist, so we should index it by that instead.